# How to put a delay timer on a micro motor small Area

Tags: motor, timer, delay

I am trying to put a micro motor  basically as small as I can inside of a 1"or so wide tube like a long fishing plug, I am going to put a small prop or propeller on one end. What I need is to be able to have that motor to run that prop maybe run on a 3v battery, I need the motor to run on a delay to kick on run the prop for 1 or 2 seconds shut off then in about 3 seconds kick on and continue do the same thing,  any suggestions on what I would have to do to make a motor do that cheaply Don

Answer (score 1):

A 555 timer in an astable configuration should do the trick. You can't get a shorter on period than the off period, so you'll need to use some kind of signal inverting element. Here i'm using an N-type mosfet to control the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYhjnz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>